# Laravel subquery relationship

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, eloquent

Here is my Schema:

The `User` model is normal.

```
Question
  - team_id
  - question_body
```

```
Answer
  - user_id
  - question_id
  - order
  - is_private
```

A user can have a primary answer for a question which is essentially the answer that has the lowest order and is public.

I need to get the primary answer of a question for each user except the authenticated user. Here is what I have so far on the Question model:

```
return User::with(['answers' => function ($query) {
    return $query->where('question_id', $this->getKey())
        ->orderBy('order')
        ->public();
}])
   ->where('id', '!=', Auth::user()->getKey())
   ->get();
```

In my test I am creating a user with two public answers and another user with a private answer and then a public answer. The private answer for the second user has a lower order. When I run the test I get the users with all their public answers to the given question ordered by `order`. I just want the first one so I add `first()` to the subquery and it gives me the correct data for the user with two public answers but for the second user it returns an empty collection. If anyone has any ideas they would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: use the relation correctly user-question liaison

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best thing to do here is to declare a new relation in the `User::class`

```php
lass User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function publicAnswer()
    {
        $query = Answer::orderBy('order', 'asc')->public();
        return $this->newHasOne($query, Answer::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Then you can use this relation in your query

```php
return User::with(['publicAnswer' => function ($query) {
    return $query->where('question_id', $this->getKey());
}])
   ->where('users.id', '!=', Auth::user()->getKey())
   ->get();
```

The difference is that `public_answer` attribute on user will not be a collection but an instance of `Answer::class` (or `null`)

The issue here is if you dont filter with `question_id` (`$query->where('question_id', $this->getKey())`), the result will be just the first public answer from the the first question which would not make any sense.